# Check for dataframe columns containing more than 64 characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the column in the Pandas dataframe that has more than 64 characters.

The dataframe has 20 columns. I want to check each value in the column for its character length and if any value is more than 64 characters, print the column name.

When I use the below code, it does not give any error, but does not output the column name which has values matching the condition.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if (df[col].str.len()).any() > 64:
        print col
```

I have also made sure that all the datatypes in the dataframe are of String type.

How can I achieve this using Pandas?

Comment: Replace `any` by `max`, it may work better. or the `any` should be around the comparison `(df[col].str.len() > 64).any()`

Comment: @Ben.T : This worked. Thanks for the quick reply. How do I mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use `any`, then it has to be around the comparison, such as:

```
if (df[col].str.len() > 64).any()
```

but you can also just compare to the `max`:

```
if (df[col].str.len()).max() > 64
```

Both should give the same result

Answer (score 4):

If all of your columns are strings:

```
df.applymap(len).gt(64).any()
```

#### Sample Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                   'X': ['aewrarwqreawfqwerawefqrqwdfawerq2fadsfaqreadfqrawdfawedfeadcfawfawefafrr', '1', '8'],
                   'Y': ['', '714', '']})

df.applymap(len).gt(64).any()
#0    False
#X     True
#Y    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: You can select only string columns with `df.select_dtypes('object')`

Comment: @ALollz : When I try your code, I get an error "(object of type 'float' has no len())". But all the column datatypes are of "object" type.

Comment: @Raj, an object column is capable of holding mixed dtypes. So you likely have a mixture of strings and numeric types in each column. In that case you could do `df.astype('str').applymap(len).gt(64).any()`.

Comment: Yeah, just be careful about what you actually want. `pd.Series.str.len` will return `NaN` for numeric types, though perhaps you want to count 65 digit numbers? `.astype(str)` can sometimes have annoying consequences with integers in float columns (adding a .0), leading to a calculated length that is a few characters off from what you'd expect